# Error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine

```
public Point[] calc_peaks (Mat im,
                   Point[] points,
                   OpenCvSharp.CvSize ssize)
    {
            int n = points.Length;
            Mat matpoints = OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.MatOfPoint2f (points);
            using (Mat pt = (new MatOfPoint2f (matpoints)).Reshape (1, 2 * n))
```

I tried this code on Unity and it says there is an Cs0119 Error at :

```
Mat matpoints = OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.MatOfPoint2f (points)
```

It drives me crazy!I tried to delete the error line;however it says:

> error CS1503: Argument #1' cannot convert `OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.Point[]` expression to type `System.IntPtr`

Answer (score 2):

pretty sure the problem is that MatOfPoint2f() wants a Point, but you are giving it an array of Points

Comment: So how can I give the array of Points to the Mat pt? I tried to use a loop;and the code is     for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
   matpoints.GetArray(1,j,points);
  }